# How to combine two pl/sql select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having 3 select statement with same tables but with different columns and I want to give result in single set of result if I give input as 1 then it should run 1st select statement if I give 2 input it should run 2nd select statement.
And I am sorry I can't copy my code here as it is too big and security purposes of my office work so can any one please suggest the ways to do it.and I am new to plsql so it's very difficult for me to find on google

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Perhaps you could include a simplified example that shows what you are trying to do using dummy tables.

Comment: [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) is a desktop application. [PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/overview.html) is Oracle's in-database programming language. [SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/sql.html#GUID-DA48618A-A6BB-421A-A10A-02859D8ED9AD) is a query language. It sounds like your question is about SQL, not the other two.

Answer (score 0):

what I understand you need to create two select depend to specific condition:
You will play on param1 and param2 value like that:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_sp (param1 VARCHAR2, param2 VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    IF param1 IS NULL AND param2 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT ...
        INTO ... -- Assumed
        FROM ...
        WHERE my_column = p_DrumNo;
    ELSE
        SELECT ...
        INTO ... -- Assumed
        FROM ...
        WHERE ORDER_ID IN (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM ORDERDELIVERY);
    END;
END;
```

Notice: the attribute that I used on this example is a random example , don't forget to change it by your attributes .

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: I am having only read only access so can only use select clause can't create procedure any other way? I need to creat select statement in such a way that I can include all these select statements in single query and  if I want to run 1st select statement then it should only run 1st select statement

Comment: You should create this procedure or ask your DB admin for that because it's not possible to use if statement using sql , you need to move to pl-sql.

Comment: Yeah I need this in pl/sql only can you suggest any solution?